# Is there a way to add 2 checkbox choices together to get the sum?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I wrote a program where the user can build their own phone plan. They have a two checkboxes that allows them to add email and text messages to their plan. If they want only email, it will be an extra $25. If they only want txt messages, it will be an additional $10. If they check both boxes, it should amount to $35.
My code works when they only click one of the checkboxes but not both. When the user checks off both, it returns 25 instead of 35. I'll include the part of the code that is relevant to the question below.

```
    If chkEmail.Checked = True Then
        dblOptions = 25
    ElseIf chkTxt.Checked = True Then
        dblOptions = 10
    ElseIf chkEmail.Checked = True And chkTxt.Checked = True Then
        dblOptions = 35
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saying what language you're using, but based on syntax I guess it might be VB.Net? You could do it like this:

```
If chkEmail.Checked = True And chkTxt.Checked = True Then
  dblOptions = 35
ElseIf chkEmail.Checked = True Then
  dblOptions = 25
ElseIf chkTxt.Checked = True Then
  dblOptions = 10
End If
```

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot to add that, but, yes it is VB. Your code worked! Is there a reason why the code worked when I moved the line of code that checks for both to the top instead of the bottom?

Comment: @mike1319 Yes, the order you try the conditions is important, in your example you could never reach the last elseif statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is matching the `If` condition, so it doesn't check any of the `ElseIf` conditions.  Putting the check for both boxes first would fix this (as in jpw's answer).

Alternatively, you could separate the checks from one another, like this:

```
dblOptions = 0
If chkEmail.Checked Then
    dblOptions += 25
End If
If chkTest.Checked Then
    dblOptions += 10
End If
```

It's a little more verbose now, but it has the advantage that if you eventually have a third option you only have to add one more `If` statement instead of several.

Comment: This is how I would do it too, but I couldn't remember VB syntax, so I modified the code already there :p

Comment: Yeah, I had to fire up VS to syntax check this one. :)